# How can I fix my MIPS code for nested for loops?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I am trying to find out where I am going wrong with my MIPS code.

I am tasked with translating the following C code:

```
for(i=0;i<a;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<b;j++)
    {
        D[j]=i+j;
    }
}
```

I have been given the following information about the code:
Values of a,b,i,j are stored in $s0,$s1,$t0,$t1 respectively. Also, the base address for the array D is stored in $s2.

Here is my current translation:

```
LoopOuter:   slt $t2, $t0, $s0 #(i<a), if true then $t2=1
             bne $t2, 0, Exit
LoopInner:   slt $t2, $t1, $s1 #(j<b), if true then $t2=1
             bne $t2, 0, ReturnOuter
             sll $t3, $t1, 2 #Get the offset.
             add $t3, $t3, $s2 #Contains the element D[j]
             add $t4, $t0, $t1 #Add i+j and save to $t5
             sw $t3, $t4 #Save to the D[j]=i+j
             addi $t1, $t1, 1 #j++
             j LoopInner
ReturnOuter: addi $t0, $t0, 1 #i++
             j LoopOuter
Exit:
```

Where am I going wrong and how do I fix it?

Edit:
After reading Eriks amazing reply I have attempted to revise my code taking into account what he told me, here is the new updated code:

```
LoopOuter:   slt $t2, $t0, $s0
             beq $t2, $zero, Exit
             add $t1, $zero, $zero
LoopInner:   slt $t2, $zero, $s1
             beq $t2, $zero, ReturnOuter

             sll $t3, $t1, 2 #$t3 = 4*j
             add $t4, $t1, $t2
             sw  $t4, $t3($s2) #Save i+j to D[j]

             addi $t1, $t1, 1 #j++
             j LoopInner
ReturnOuter: addi $t0, $t0, 1 #i++
             j LoopOuter
Exit:
```

Edit 2:
The assumptions for this task are that all values in the required registers already contain the needed data, such that $t0 and $t1 are zeroed.

Answer (score 1):

The `bne` instruction, when used after `slt`, says to branch when the condition is true.  But in assembly language, we often branch away from something, whereas in C we often say when to do or continue something.  Those `bne`s are being used to ***exit*** the loops, so you need to branch when the condition is false, e.g. using `beq` instead.  If the loop continuation condition is ***false*** then branch to exit the loop.

---

You have skipped some parts of the for loops.

Let's translate them into while loops to make it clear:

```
i = 0;                      <---- where is this??
while(i<a)
{
    j = 0;                  <---- where is this??
    while(j<b)
    {
        D[j]=i+j;
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Do you notice something that's in this both the for loop form and this while loop form, but missing in your assembly?  Check each line.

---

```
add $t3, $t3, $s2 #Contains the element D[j]
```

Just to be clear, this produces the memory address of element `D[j]`.  Though it probably won't affect your program, this should be using `addu` because pointers are unsigned and pointer arithmetic should use unsigned arithmetic.  Your other `add`s and `addi`s are ok assuming `i` & `j` are signed integers.

---

```
sw $t3, $t4 #Save to the D[j]=i+j
```

Not sure what assembler is allowing this, but (1) the operands are backwards.  `$t3` is the address and should be the 2nd operand, and `$t4` is the value of `i+j` and should be the first operand.

And (2) the memory address operand is traditionally written with ()'s surrounding, and sometimes even a leading constant, e.g. `($t3)`, or, `0($t3)`.

Comment: Can you take a look at my edit and see if I managed to fix some of the issues that you mentioned. Thank you for this reply. It was very informative.

Comment: (1) The beq's are an improvement.  (2) you're still missing part of the for loops, reread that section of my answer. (3) there's no reason to have a `lw`, that would only be if D[?] was found on the right hand side of something, like `... = D[j]`. Or else if there was `D[j] += i+j` as that would require both reading and writing the same element.  (3) Otherwise, please reread my answer carefully.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot to add the assumptions that were provided for this task. I was to assume that all values have already being zeroed at the start of the program. Also the lw is for the D[j]=i+j. Is that not the correct way to do that?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work: j needs to be zeroed dynamically, that is inside a loop.

Comment: How do you figure to use lw to store into D[j].  It is either lw or sw but not both.

Comment: Does lw not load the value from the memory to the register? Then I change that value and save it with sw. Or do I just save it to the adress.

Comment: How does the code in the edit look now?